# while migrating mysql data from a table to another, null values in mysql is converted to none in python

Tags: python, mysql, migration, mysql-connector

```
    import mysql.connector
    import os
    import configparser
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host= "localhost", user= "root", passwd= "1234", database= "testdb")
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
#taking schema dump
    os.popen("mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p1234 --no-data testdb > testdb.sql")
    mycursor.execute("SELECT id FROM workspaces")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for i in myresult:
        dbname = "ak_shc_"+'%s' %(i)
        print(dbname)
        input_db = mysql.connector.connect(host= "localhost", user= "root", passwd= "1234")
        inputcursor = input_db.cursor()
        inputcursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s" % (dbname))
        os.popen("mysql -h localhost -u root -p1234 %s < testdb.sql" % (dbname))
        insert_data = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="1234", database= '%s' % (dbname))
        insertcursor = insert_data.cursor()
#selecting data to be migrated
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM workspaces WHERE id=%s" % (i))
        values = mycursor.fetchall()
        for a in values:
            print(a)
#restoring data
            insertcursor.execute("INSERT INTO workspaces VALUES " + str(tuple(a)))



    **
```

> error:
> > >mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'None' in 'field list' You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> > manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '[(1, 'ws_1', None, datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 29,
> 6, 6, 14), 'zxcv', 0, None, No' at line 1
> enter code here

**

Comment: Sounds to me like you're using string formatting instead of placeholders with `cursor.execute()` parameters.

Comment: You need to post the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: code has been added